# Is it possible to detect C/C++/Java variable declarations.?

Tags: cc-mode, syntax-table, parsing

I'm writing a [minor mode](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/electric-operator) to handle automatic spacing of operator characters, but I'm having some trouble with C/C++. The problem is that I can't figure out how to tell in general whether a `*` is a multiplication or a pointer type. Similarly for `&`, and `<`/`>` in C++ .

I've currently got some basic hacks to detect the built in types (`int`, `char`, etc.) and to detect types ending in `_t`. I've also found the `c-guess-basic-syntax` function which can tell me when point is in a function header so I can handle function argument and return types. However I can't find any way to detect when point is in a normal variable declaration.

Is it possible without implementing a C compiler?

Comment: It should be possible for C, but not for C++ given the high complexity of the language. Probably explains why the approach of shelling out to `clang` is popular there.

Comment: If you don't mind the overhead, `semantic` should be able to give you all the information you need. Open up cpp file and start semantic mode and run `(semantic-fetch-tags)` in it, you'll see a ton of information that can be useful to you. Also with your point inside a function you can run `(semantic-get-local-variables)` which will give you the list of local variables and where they are declared in the current function.